# HTML cache version

Tags: html, caching

You know how if you use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="urlhere.js?version=1.0.0"></script>
```

the browser caches the javascript file and updates it when you give it a new version?

Is there a way to do that with the HTML code?

Because I want the browser to cache the HTML, but then update when the code is changed.

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you using static HTML or is this HTML generated by some server side script? If it's pure static HTML file your web server already takes care of it. When you update the HTML file on the server it will detect that the timestamp has changed and serve the new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle caching would be at the server level, specifying two tags:

- [`Expires`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21)
  When the date specified has past, it tells the browser the content is no longer valid and it must be refreshed.
- [`Cache-Control`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9)
  Without involving the date, it lets the browser know how it should handling caching for the page.

**Note:** The browser should already take care of this as it (in the background) already looks at the last modified date of the file. However, the above methods are valid ways of overriding (extending) this kind of detection in places where the last modified date may not necessarily reflect change.